How do I create a macro that adds a new series with specific data ranges on the current sheet to an existing chart?
I have a chart and I would like to add another data series on a secondary axis. It seems like it should be simple, but I can't get it to dynamically add the current sheet name to the data series. I looked all over the web and landed on this, but it still won't run. How can I fix this?
Sub PyGraph()
'
' PyGraph Macro
'

'
    With ActiveChart
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""CL"""
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet & "!$F$2:$F$256"
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet & "!$H$2:$H$256"
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
    End With
    
End Sub


Untested, but try "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!$F$2:$F$256"

@BigBen Omg I can't believe I spent the last 2 hours on this. It was those apostrophes... I had deleted them in my original attempt. Thank you

You need to include the worksheet .Name, and to surround it with ' to handle the case of spaces in the name.
.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!$F$2:$F$256"
.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!$H$2:$H$256"

